# findFragmentByID() returns null using container ID immediately after it is created

Tags: android, android-fragments

Note I've checked the *very* numerous "duplicates" of this question and none of them fit the bill, so please don't mark this as a duplicate.

I modified the default wizard-created app (in Android Studio) to try to find the placeholder fragment after it is created, like this (the only statement added is the `Log` line):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    Log.d("", "Found fragment: " + getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container));
}
```

However the log just prints:

> Found fragment: null

According to what I've read of the documentation and answers to similar questions, it should work. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment transaction has not yet been executed but just scheduled for later execution.

Wait for `super.onStart()` in the application lifecycle, of if you're impatient, call [`executePendingTransactions()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29).